# Could not able to get the reponse printed in the console

Tags: prototypejs, prototype

I use the following code to get the response printed in the console. But i'm getting as null in the console.

In the index.php url i have the JSON code

```
new Ajax.Request('http://10.239.50.92/sample/index.php', {
 method:'get', 
  onSuccess: function(products){  
                //alert(products.hasOwnProperty(value));  
                //alert(products.hasOwnProperty());
                console.log(products.responseJSON);
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it will help:

```
new Ajax.Request('http://10.239.50.92/sample/index.php', {
  method:'get',

  onSuccess: function (transport) {
    var response = transport.responseText;
    var json = eval('(' + response + ')')
    console.log(json);
  }
});
```

*Or try to change header in http response, but it seems there some difficulties with this issue in prototype.*

Comment: Hi Speransky, I have a similar issue, and I seem to figure out the cause, 
I am using perl/cgi on the back end, my code is as follows

Comment: `new Ajax.Request('ajax-sr-update.cgi', {

  method: 'get',
  onSuccess: function(transport) {
   var response = transport.responseText;
      var json = eval('(' + response + ')')
      console.log(json);
   if (json) {
    if (json.error_message) {
     do something;
    } else if (json.incident_id) {
     do something-else;
    } else {
     display a general error
    }
   } else {
    general error
   }
  },
  onFailure: function(data) {
   display failed
  }
 });`

Answer (score 0):

The responseJSON field will only be returned if the response type of the AJAX request is "application/json".

I would try the following:

```
console.log(transport)
```

to see if the responseJSON property is available to you.

Comment: dtsn, you were right I was not getting any json values in the return, it was all in plain text. Thanks for the idea.